# How can I read old comm messages?

Tags: ingress

Is there way to read messages older than what's shown on the comm?
Sometimes there happen to be some chatter on the comm which I can't catch at the moment and try to read later in the day but can't because they happen to be in older times than my comm starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can read all messages ever written on the comm but you can't do it with the ingress app. You have to switch to the ingress [web intel page](https://www.ingress.com/intel), zoom into a location, press on the "COMM" title of the comm window in the lower left corner and then by scrolling up the messages go back till the date you are looking for.

Don't forget that you'll see every notification you did get in the past when you do this.

This method is too cumbersome to get the messages you're looking for and it's location limited but there aren't other ways to get those messages right now.

Comment: No you can't see every message. I checked different locations and all i could see was max. 1 month old.

Comment: There seems to be some sort of limit to how far back you can go but it varies based on location